How to type an endpoint to cover potential variations in the data
I'm converting legacy project from JS to TS and I'm learning TS at the same time.
I've stumbled upon an endpoint that has many different variants of responses.
Let's say I only know part of the types, like in example below:
export interface Payload {
  header: Header;
  person: Person;
}

export interface Person {
  timestamp: string;
  name: string;
  surname: string;
}

But then Payload might also have some other fields that I don't know of. Like - for the sake of example - "age" or "height". But the endpoint might happen to return (for a different person) for example "vitals: Vitals" object.
How do I account for that?
Do I have to run the endpoint and "map it out" for all possible variants of the returned payload? Or is there a more clever way to to that?

This is a bit light on details to have an objective answer. You either need to just leave the interfaces general and then deal with the fact that your code doesn't know about these hypothetical other properties, or you define all the variants you care about and narrow your types to them where necessary.  If you could provide a [mre] then we could give more specific directions. Currently it's lacking the details I'd need to say anything more concrete.

There's a huge difference between might return vitals but sometimes might not return it and might return anything of any type, might be vitals, might be vitals2 or even whateverelse3. Endpoints that return totally dynamic data are often avoided, thus, make sure which case you are actually in. The most reliable source of knowledge would be the documentation of the endpoint.

There are a few answers for your question. 
TypeScript is used to introduce types to js. 
If you declare a type for a response you, as a developer, know what to expect from said response. 
But this type for your object does not impact your code at runtime. 
So for your questions:

How do I account for that?

Usually you should know what you get as a response. 
Thats the whole reason for types. You should know what you get.

Should I map it out?

No. You could test for different types with something like this. But thats only a good option if you know that the response has different types with guaranteed keys.
    if (response.age) {
        // Do Stuff
    }


Is there a clever way?

Ignore unmapped values or add them to your types. 
If your response contains values that arent included in your types your code will still run.

OK, the answer is to use index signatures:
export interface Person {
  timestamp: string;
  name: string;
  surname: string;
  [key: string]: string;
}

In this case when we try to access response.person.whatever TypeScript won't protest with Property 'whatever' does not exist on type 'Person'.

Please consider [edit]ing the question with a [mre] to motivate  this answer. Ideally something that shows you trying to do response.person.whatever and then has a problem, and mentions that you just want whatever to be a string (and apparently you don't care if it's not really there, so that it's undefined at runtime but string according to TS).  Currently the question has so few details about what you're doing that the only reason you'd know that this is the right answer is because you were the one who asked the question. Future readers don't have that benefit.

OK, good point. I'll edit the question.
